# How to download excel file from nodejs terminal

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am new to nodejs. Need your help. From the nodejs terminal, i want to download an excel file and convert it to csv (say, `mocha online.js`). Note: i don't want to do this via a browser.

Below is a script i am working on to download and convert to csv. There is no error nor the expected result:

**online.js**

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
var url = "http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/test_files/formula_stress_test_ajax.xlsx";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
describe('suite', function () {
    it('case', function () {
    var arraybuffer = xhr.response;

    /* convert data to binary string */
    var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    var bstr = arr.join("");

    /* Call XLSX */
    var sheetName = 'Database';
    var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
    var csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
    console.log(csv);
    xhr.send();  
    //.... perform validations here using the csv data 
    });
})}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Mocha? Mocha is a unit testing framework. I don't see any test code in your snippet.

Comment: Hello @PatrickHund, thanks. i have updated the original. The challenge i have is to get the test data from the online excel when executing test mocha test via the `node terminal`. From `testrunner.html` the script works if i add `xhr.onload = function (e) {`. So current problem is, I just cannot get this to trigger when executing this mocha test from the node terminal. Please help. Is this possible via the terminal?

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself with this code, and it seems it is working, the only thing is that I spent 15 minutes trying to understand why my open office would not open the file, I eventually understood that they were sending a zip file ... here is the full code, the doc of the http get function is here [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

You could have used the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, but it isn't native, request is easier though.

enjoy!

```
const url = 'http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/test_files/formula_stress_test_ajax.xlsx'
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

http.get(url, (res) => {
    debugger
    const {
        statusCode
    } = res;
    const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
    console.log(`The type of the file is : ${contentType}`)
    let error;
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error(`Request Failed.\n` +
            `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
    }
    if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        // consume response data to free up memory
        res.resume();
        return;
    }
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        rawData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            const parsedData = xlsxToCSVFunction(rawData);
            // And / Or just put it in a file
            fs.writeFileSync('fileName.zip', rawData, 'binary')
                // console.log(parsedData);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});


function xlsxToCSVFunction(rawData) {
    return rawData //you should return the csv file here whatever your tools are
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amine for your patient time on this. This is helpful.

Comment: well you first said I had the answer then you switched to your own answer..

Comment: oh! i did'nt know that we cannot mark multiple correct answer. what a shame. i marked it back in fifo style :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually encountered the same problem 3 months ago : here is what I did!

I did not find any nodeJS module that was exactly as I wanted, so I used in2csv (a python shell program) to transform the data; the t option is to use tabulation as the delimiter

1) Step 1: transforming the xlsx file into csv using in2csv
This code takes all the xlsx files in the current directory, transform them into csv files and put them in another directory

```
var shelljs = require('shelljs/global')
var dir = pwd().stdout.split('/')
dir = dir[dir.length - 1].replace(/\s/g, '\\ ')
mkdir('../'+ dir + 'CSV')
ls('*.xlsx').forEach(function(file) {
// below are the two lines you need
    let string = 'in2csv -t ' + file.replace(/\s/g, '\\ ') + ' > ../'+ dir + 'CSV/' + file.replace('xlsx','csv').replace(/\s/g, '\\ ')
    exec(string, {silent:true}, function(code, stdout, stderr){
        console.log('new file : ' + file.replace('xlsx','csv'))
        if(stderr){
            console.log(string)
            console.log('Program stderr:', stderr)
        }
    })
});
```

Step 2: loading the data in a nodejs program:

my script is very long but the main two lines are :

```
const args = fileContent.split('\n')[0].split(',')
const content = fileContent.split('\n').slice(1).map(e => e.split(','))
```

Comment: Thank @Amine, for this. For converting xlsx to csv i use the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) module as shown in the original question. I am looking at how we can download the excel file from online via the nodejs terminal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**And for the benefit of seekers like me...`here is a solution using mocha, request and xlsx`**

```
var request = require('request');
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
describe('suite', function () {
    it('case', function (done) {
        var url = "http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/test_files/formula_stress_test_ajax.xlsx";
        var options = {
          url: url,
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
          },
          encoding: null
        };     
        request.get(options, function (err, res, body){
          var arraybuffer = body;
          /* convert data to binary string */
          var data = arraybuffer;            
          //var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);                
          var arr = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
          var bstr = arr.join("");
          /* Call XLSX */
          var sheetName = 'Database';
          var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
          var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
          var csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
          console.log(csv);
          done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @Amine, it works for me (as-is). Retried the above pasted code snippet after reading your feedback. I am using the current latest versions of node, mocha, request and xlsx. I am running from the termial using `mocha mytest.js`. Thanks.

Comment: Tnx, it is good to know that xlsx is doing this for you, I would use the xlsx module for the xlsxToCSVFunction in my response above instead of using the classic in2csv (it was more of a hack)